# What are the different work statuses on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I've recently seen this in the "About" section of a Facebook profile.

[image]

---

It links to a "[Work Status](https://www.facebook.com/pages/Work-From-Home/1458078967813397?pnref=about.work)" page which looks official (but is it?).

[image]

Are there any other work statuses and are they listed anywhere? It would be nice to have a complete list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A work status defines someone's job or occupation of the day if it doesn't involve a company.

It appears that they were widely used by the community under some "Interest" or "Community" pages and were finally merged and sorted by Facebook under a more descent category, "Work status".

---

I didn't find a complete list but stumbled upon some of them.

- [Unemployed](https://www.facebook.com/pages/Unemployed/236956376428767)
- [Not Yet Working](https://www.facebook.com/pages/Not-Yet-Working/359909574172595)
- [Stay-at-home parent](https://www.facebook.com/pages/Stay-at-home-parent/1393703070850292)
- [Retired](https://www.facebook.com/pages/Retired/170135829826980)
- [Self-employed](https://www.facebook.com/pages/Self-Employed/594445203920155)
- [Work From Home](https://www.facebook.com/pages/Work-From-Home/1458078967813397) (synonym page: [Remote work](https://www.facebook.com/pages/Remote-work/127239100772139))
- [Student](https://www.facebook.com/pages/Student/452244444871895)
- [None](https://www.facebook.com/pages/None/645052995582501)

And their respective icons:

[image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image]

*Feel free to complete the list.*